# Multiple PHP subqueries not giving desired result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table from which I want to extract attendance information(Student Id, course/subject for attendance, date range,whether the student was present or not). I have written the following query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(a_id),
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance
    WHERE state = 'present' 
      AND `dater` BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
  ) AS Count,
  stud_id
FROM attendance
WHERE
  stud_id =(SELECT id FROM users WHERE NAME = '$stud')
```

Which is giving me the correct results, but when I change the student,its not giving me the correct count for the days recorded for present. Not mention that I have not yet added the course parameter into the query

[image]
[image]

The MySQL table is as follows:
[image]

I need help for the query to return the desired results(Count the accurate days present for each student, as well as adding the course parameter into the query so that the query will look for attendance records for a specific course, for a specific student, for a specified date range).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to seperate your queries:

```
Select (select count(*) from <database>.attendance where state = 'present' AND (dater between '$a' and '$b') AND name=(SELECT id FROM users WHERE NAME = '$stud')) as present, (select count(*) from <database>.attendance where state = 'absent' AND (dater between '$a' and '$b') AND name=(SELECT id FROM users WHERE NAME = '$stud')) as absent from <database>.attendance WHERE stud_id =(SELECT id FROM users WHERE NAME = '$stud');
```

try this :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it using JOIN as follows:

```
SELECT u.id, a.stud_id, a.course_id, count(*) FROM attendance a 
JOIN users u ON u.id=a.stud_id 
JOIN courses c ON c.c_id=a.course_id
WHERE a.state='present' and dater between '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-14'
GROUP BY a.stud_id, a.course_id;
```

Thanks for your help.